# Read/Write a FILE with filename containing a forward slash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, file-io

How can I read/write a FILE with filename containing Forward slashes (/)?

This is what I'm trying to do -

```
filename = "A/B/C"

full_path = "#{Rails.root}/public/barcodes/#{filename}.png"

File.open(full_path, 'w') { |f| f.write @barcode_png.to_png(:margin => 3, :xdim => 2,:ydim => 2, :height => 100) }
```

Everytime I execute this, Ruby tries to find a folder by name `A, B and C` instead of writing a file `"A/B/C"`

Any thoughts on how to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't it an invalid filename? Anyhow, you can try escaping the slashes (`\/`).

Comment: Hey, thanks for dropping in @SergioTulentsev. It is possible to create a file by name "A/B/C". However, when I try escaping slashes, like so `"A\/B\/C"`, `File.open` still tries to find for folders `A, B and C`. Any thoughts?

Comment: How do you create such filenames? I tried a couple of things and failed.

Comment: Hi @SergioTulentsev, you are right. I wasn't able to create such filenames. My bad! :) 
Everytime I created `"A/B/C"`, it ended up being `"A:B:C"`. Using "/" in filenames is prohibited! Thanks for helping out.